# docker container is always in paused state

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, devops, docker-swarm

I have a docker-compose file for the linuxserver/unifi-controller as below:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  unifi-controller:
    image: linuxserver/unifi-controller
    container_name: unifi-controller
    restart: always
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - MEM_LIMIT=1024M
    volumes:
      - ./data:/config
    ports:
      - 3478:3478/udp
      - 10001:10001/udp
    #restart: unless-stopped
    #restart: always
```

After docker-compose up, the docker container goes in the Paused state after 5 minutes. I have tried docker unpause as well, but did not work.

I am using

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.13 (stretch)
Release:    9.13
Codename:   stretch
```

and

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.14
```

Could someone please help me on this to solve? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried looking at the logs for your container instance?

Answer (score 0):

Below ports are opened in docker-compose.yml -

```
  - 1900:1900/udp
  - 5514:5514
```

And it worked.